# ExpressJS: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have an API in ExpressJS. Within that API I have a login endpoint, when posting to that endpoint however I keep getting the exception that headers cannot be set after they have been sent.

I understand this is normally a callback that is being called twice or not properly returning from something that has set headers, causing the app to attempt to set them again, however in my `/login` endpoint I am not doing this.

I cannot understand why this happening, I would love some input as to why as I am close to pulling my hair out reading the same replies and answers. I hope it is something obvious I am missing.

```
import User from '../../models/user';
import { Router } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default () => {
  const route = Router();

  route.post('/create', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'username or password is missing' });
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const count = await User.count({ email });

    if (count > 0) {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: 'email must be unique' });
    }

    const newUser = await new User({ email, password });
    const doc = await newUser.save();

    return res.status(201).json({ type: 'account', attributes: doc });
  });

  route.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) {
        user.comparePassword(password, isMatch => {
          if (isMatch) {
            const token = jwt.sign(
              { sub: user.id, roles: [], email: user.email },
              process.env.SECRET_KEY,
              { expiresIn: '12h' },
            );

            return res
              .status(200)
              .json({ type: 'account', attributes: { token } });
          }
        });
      }
    }
    res.sendStatus(401);
  });

  return route;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import User from '../../models/user';
import { Router } from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export default () => {
  const route = Router();

  route.post('/create', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: 'username or password is missing' });
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const count = await User.count({ email });

    if (count > 0) {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: 'email must be unique' });
    }

    const newUser = await new User({ email, password });
    const doc = await newUser.save();

    return res.status(201).json({ type: 'account', attributes: doc });
  });

  route.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
      const { email, password } = req.body;

      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) {
        return user.comparePassword(password, isMatch => {
          if (isMatch) {
            const token = jwt.sign(
              { sub: user.id, roles: [], email: user.email },
              process.env.SECRET_KEY,
              { expiresIn: '12h' },
            );

            return res
              .status(200)
              .json({ type: 'account', attributes: { token } });
          } else {
             return res.status(400)
               .json({ message: 'username or password is invalid' });
           }
        });
      }
    }
    res.sendStatus(401);
  });

  return route;
};
```

Have a look at the updated code return was missing at

`return user.comparePassword(password, isMatch => {`

Hope it'll fix your issue.

Comment: What if passwords doesn't match, this will return undefined, and client will not getting response from the server, resulting on timed out error

Comment: You'll have to handle else part of  if (isMatch) {  } else { // your code }

Comment: I cannot see the else part in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem in here. Your callback in comparePassword return only inside that callback. So the code still run to `res.sendStatus(401)` and after the callback is done it will run `res.status(200).json...`

```
user.comparePassword(password, isMatch => {
              if (isMatch) {
                const token = jwt.sign(
                  { sub: user.id, roles: [], email: user.email },
                  process.env.SECRET_KEY,
                  { expiresIn: '12h' },
                );

                return res
                  .status(200)
                  .json({ type: 'account', attributes: { token } });
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to promisify `comparePassword` method in the user model:

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password) {

    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(password === this.password);
    });

}
```

Now you can use `await` syntax to get the promise result:

```
route.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (user) {

            const isMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);

            if (isMatch) {
                const token = jwt.sign(
                    { sub: user.id, roles: [], email: user.email },
                    process.env.SECRET_KEY,
                    { expiresIn: '12h' },
                );

                return res
                    .status(200)
                    .json({ type: 'account', attributes: { token } });
            }
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(401);
});
```